# Can I ride the unicorn? If not, can I kill the unicorn?

Tags: unikong

I'd like to ride the unicorn as pictured both in the ad on the right as well as in the game main menu:

[image: Unikong main menu screen]

The unicorn seems to be an unkillable monster and I am unable to defeat it; I have to either dodge or use the photon blaster to set him back a few inches.

I tried goomba stomping it, tried charging head on, but I keep dying every time.

Even a highly powerful, high-density rainbow photon beam blaster didn't do anything to the unicorn; it merely pushed it back, without actually doing damage.

[image: Unikong in-game screenshot]

The picture to play depicts a valiant J Skeet on his steed; I'd like to know how I can ride the horse just as he does.  If not, then I'd like to know how to beat the unicorn and perhaps take his horn home to put on my trophy wall.

[image: Unikong intro screen]

Is there a way to ride the unicorn? Is there a way to defeat this vile unicorn? If not, is there any way to ride him as depicted in their ad?

Comment: There's a book on Amazon titled "How to Kill a Unicorn". I'll get back to you in 3-5 business days.

Comment: Everyone knows you must be "pure" to ride the unicorn. Since we're on the internet we can probably assume we all have been tainted.

Comment: I bet Jon Skeet can ride the unicorn

Comment: @Winter any update on the unicorn-killing?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Definitely invulnerable and nothing more.

Shooting a unicorn:

```
this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.boss, this.ammo, function(t, e) {
    e.kill()
}
```

does the same as shooting a platform:

```
this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.platforms, this.ammo, function(t, e) {
    e.kill()
}
```

i.e. destroys the projectile but not the object shot.

Furthermore, any collisions with the unicorn simply end in death:

```
this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.boss, this.loseGame, null, this)
```

Comment: Please tell me there's a secret line in code that says something like "if jonskeet(), give player unicorn mount"

Comment: @skully Gee there might be. I wouldn't be surprised if he was fed a different version of the game

Comment: how do I view this source code? I tried ctrl+U in chrome and it showed the page source html, but I could not find the lines of code mentioned in the answer there

Comment: What a scam! I guess the boxart is always looking better than the actual game.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie

Comment: @Lee - He gets to play as the Unicorn and automatically draws all the coins and badges to himself.

Comment: Which leads to the question - can anyone think of anything particularly fun we can do with the unicorn, using script insertion?

Comment: @user13267 I believe this is the code to control the game. http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/unikong.js?v=e54129610ca2

Comment: @MarchHo Please post you TVTropes links in spoilers. My tab count just exploded :p

Comment: @MarchHo <insert random insult for linking a TV Tropes page> <also insert cry for help, since now I'm stuck reading TV Tropes at work!>

Answer (score 49):

Running into the unicorn will kill you and shooting it pushes it back slightly. As far as i can tell you cannot kill it. I have currently shot it over 600 times in a row and it is still walking towards me. Apparently unicorns are invulnerable.

Comment: It might die if you shoot it enough times. Maybe try for 500?

Comment: I tried running a macro which would spam the spacebar 500 times, and it has not killed the Unicorn yet. I'm setting it to 9000 to see if it does any good.

Comment: @skully i shouldve written a macro. i got to 600 times before giving up as my finger was tired.

Comment: may be it should be over 9000

Comment: @user13267 [The fools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJxwvZ5SE_c)!

Comment: It takes 6 to 8 weeks to kill, keep trying.

Answer (score 18):

The box art and menu art assets were created in parallel with game development, but the game development changed course without coordinating with art, so there's a slight discrepancy, and you cannot kill or ride the unicorn.

Comment: But it was a fun game anyways. :-)

Comment: This answer reminds me of [this box art](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dd/Mega_Man_1_box_artwork.jpg). I'm guessing quite a few of you will know it without needing to click it.